# install poedit 1.5+ in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, package-management

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 which comes with poedit 1.4.6. Is there any way to install poedit 1.5+ without compiling it from source?

update: I'd rather not upgrade to 13.04, if at all possible

Comment: Yes, upgrade to Ubuntu

Comment: I am reluctant to upgrade to a non-LTS version. Isn't there a way to install this package to 12.04?

Comment: Yes, from [sources](http://www.poedit.net/download_exp.php?utm_expid=426182-2&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.ro%2F#src) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a backport (PPA) for poedit available for Precise (12.04) available from https://launchpad.net/~schaumkeks/+archive/ppa/+sourcepub/2991913/+listing-archive-extra

You can download the .deb file here:

https://launchpad.net/~schaumkeks/+archive/ppa/+files/poedit_1.5.4-1~ubuntu12.04.1~ppa1_i386.deb

If you are looking for the 64-bit version, you can download it here:

https://launchpad.net/~schaumkeks/+archive/ppa/+files/poedit_1.5.4-1~ubuntu12.04.1~ppa1_amd64.deb

From a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>t</kbd>), navigate to your download folder and issue the command `sudo dpkg -i poedit-dbg_1.5.4-1~ubuntu12.04.1~ppa1_i386.deb`

or, to install the 64-bit version, run the following command:
`sudo dpkg -i poedit_1.5.4-1~ubuntu12.04.1~ppa1_amd64.deb`

- [What are PPAs and how do I use them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4983/what-are-ppas-and-how-do-i-use-them/40351#40351)
- [Are PPA's safe to add to my system and what are some "red flags" to watch out for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out)

Answer (score 4):

I use ubuntu 13.04, and I see poedit 1.5 can be installed simply by

```
$ sudo apt-get install poedit
```

ruuning this command

```
$ sudo apt-cache show poedit | grep "Version"
```

gives me the following result

```
Version: 1.5.4-1
```

Suggestion should be simply install by source, or upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

I know the question is a bit old, but I tried what @Kevin Bowen suggests and couldn't find the files.

I added this PPA https://launchpad.net/~schaumkeks/+archive/ppa, updated apt sources but still the installed version is ~1.4.

I downloaded the binary packages from packages in https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/poedit ([poedit-dbg_1.5.4-1_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/poedit-dbg_1.5.4-1_i386.deb) and [poedit_1.5.4-1_i386.deb](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/poedit_1.5.4-1_i386.deb), BUT, poedit dependes on libdb5.1++, which in my case wasn't installed. Just installed it from the repos and then installed `poedit_1.5.4-1_i386.deb` and `poedit-dbg_1.5.4-1_i386.deb`, in that order.

So, it isn't very hard, open your command line and:

```
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/poedit-dbg_1.5.4-1_i386.deb
wget https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archive/primary/+files/poedit_1.5.4-1_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install libdb5.1++
sudo dpkg -i poedit_1.5.4-1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i poedit-dbg_1.5.4-1_i386.deb
```

The main reason I had to do this is because version < 1.4 uses the `X-Lanauge` header instead of the `Language` header, which uses the `gettext` binary compile `.po` files.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I had no dependency issues upgrading in 12.04, downloaded the 1.5.4 deb (Trusty version) from the Ubuntu source you listed above, opened it with SoftwareCenter and 1.4.6 was upgraded successfully (1.4.6 was previously installed via SoftwareCenter to from the official/default PPA).